# Altair: Boxplot with round corners

Tags: altair

For a bar chart, I can set round corners in the following way:

```
alt.Chart(
  ...
).mark_bar(
  cornerRadiusTopLeft=4,
  cornerRadiusTopRight=4
).encode(
...
)
```

Is it somehow possible to do the same for boxplots (of course for all four corners)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the box argument using a dict, like below:

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot(box={'cornerRadius':8}, extent='min-max').encode(
    x='age:O',
    y='people:Q'
)
```

[image]

Comment: wonderful, thank you, exactly what I have been looking for :-)